# Using \fontsize and \textbf

Tags: fontsize

I need help understanding what is happening in the below example.  I am trying to set the font size to 23pts.  But it is only changing the size of the font within the `\textbf{}`. The text that fills the `#2` parameter ends up being very small.  See the picture for the example.

```
\begin{minipage}[l]{.08\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth, height=1.25cm]{./images/green_checkmark}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[c]{.92\textwidth}
\fontsize{23}{28}
%\LARGE
\textcolor{TitleColor}{\textbf{#1} #2} \\
\large
\textcolor{SubTitleColor}{#3}
\end{minipage}
```

[image: Using \Large]

However if I comment out `\Large` and uncomment `\fontsize`:

```
\begin{minipage}[c]{.92\textwidth}
%\fontsize{23}{28}
\LARGE
\textcolor{TitleColor}{\textbf{#1} #2} \\
\large
\textcolor{SubTitleColor}{#3}
\end{minipage}
```

I get:

[image]

Basically, all I want is to be able to set the font size to be something between `\LARGE` and `\huge`.

Also, I tried the below without success:

```
 \textcolor{TitleColor}{\textbf{#1} \fontsize{23}{28}#2} \
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several commands for changing font attributes; there are the lower level ones

```
\fontencoding
\fontfamily
\fontseries
\fontshape
\fontsize
```

that are used by higher level commands. Each of these commands changes one attribute (the last one requires two arguments, font size and baselineskip); however they just instruct LaTeX to change the current value of the attribute, without actually selecting it: it would be inefficient for LaTeX to compute a new current font four times with, say

```
\fontencoding{T1}\fontfamily{cmss}\fontseries{bx}\fontshape{sl}
```

so the real way to operate is choosing the various attributes and select the font with `\selectfont`. For instance, the "middle level" command

```
\usefont{T1}{cmss}{bx}{sl}
```

is equivalent to

```
\fontencoding{T1}\fontfamily{cmss}\fontseries{bx}\fontshape{sl}\selectfont
```

A `\fontXYZ` command just changes the attribute, but the change remains suspended until `\selectfont` acts. The same is for `\fontsize`.

The higher level commands such as `\bfseries` do essentially something like

```
\fontseries{bx}\selectfont
```

while `\textbf{text}` does

```
{\bfseries text}
```

and this explains the problem you get: it's the implicit `\bfseries` that does `\selectfont`, but as soon as the closing brace is scanned, the font goes back to the previously selected one.

In conclusion,

```
\fontsize{23}{32}\selectfont
```

will do. Remember either to load the `fix-cm` package or use a fully scalable font.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation in addition to the answer!