# tikz poster make all text bold

Tags: titles, bold, tikzposter

I am making a poster for presentation. I prefer tikzposter. When working on the formatting I prefer bold text everywhere so that it can be read more easily from a distance.

My code of a working example:

```
\documentclass[25pt, portrait, margin=0in, innermargin=0.5in, blockverticalspace=0.5in, colspace=0.5in, ]{tikzposter} %17, 20, 25pt  
\geometry{paperwidth=45in, paperheight=44in}  
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  


\makeatletter  
\setlength{\TP@visibletextwidth}{43.5in} %paperwidth - margin  
\setlength{ \TP@visibletextheight}{42.5in} %paperheight - margin  
\makeatother  

\usepackage{tikz} %% required for tikzposter  
\usepackage{calc} %% required for tikzposter  
\usepackage{ifthen} %% required for tikzposter  
\usepackage{ae} %% required for tikzposter  
\usepackage{xstring} %% required for tikzposter  
\usepackage{etoolbox} %% required for tikzposter  
\usepackage{xkeyval} %% required for tikzposter  
\usepackage{authblk} % for author affiliation in title section  

\usetheme{Default} %Default, Rays, Basic, Simple, Envelope, Wave, Board, Autumn, Desert  

\title{\parbox{\linewidth}{\centering\textbf{This is a really long and smart title for all the work I have done on this}}}  
\author[1]{\textbf{Smart C.}}  
\author[2]{\textbf{J. Brainy}}  
\author[2]{\textbf{M. Scientist}}  
\author[1]{\textbf{S. Proffessor}}  
\date{\today}  
\affil[1]{\textbf{University of Somewhere}}  
\affil[2]{\textbf{Commission os Something}}  
%% To avoid extra vspace between title and body % START % https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/225542/how-to-add-multiple-affiliations-in-the-tikzposter-class  
\makeatletter  
\def\maketitle{\AB@maketitle}  
\makeatother  
%% To avoid extra vspace between title and body % END  

\begin{document}  

    \maketitle  

\end{document}
```

Here, as can be seen the punctuation and the word and are not bolded. 
The question is how can I bold them. I have the same problem with a few cases in the body of the poster.

Comment: Actually, it is bold... If I remove the `\textbf{...}` the font is unbolded.  If this is not emphasized enough, perhaps you could try a larger font?

Comment: While I understand that I can remove the \textbf{} I was hoping to get that same emphasis on the automatically inserted font. Using a larger size font as opposed to using thicker font reduces the quantity of information. Also, IMHO the thicker font is more pleasing.

Comment: In that case, maybe [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122653/using-fontsize-and-textbf) or [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27843/level-of-boldness-changeable) will be helpful?  I am openly admitting to not having read them completely, but they look informative for your issue.

Comment: I haven't said anything about the body in my answer, as you weren't very clear about how those problems occurred.

Answer (score 1):

You're using `authblk`, and that package has redefinable macros for setting the format of authors and affiliation. On the other hand, the general `tikzposter` method for modifying the title formatting is, I think, to use `\settitle`.

---

The `authblk` settings you need to do is

```
\renewcommand\Authfont{\bfseries}
\renewcommand\Affilfont{\bfseries}
```

and if you want the superscript numbers bold as well, add

```
\renewcommand\AB@authnote[1]{\textsuperscript{#1}}
\renewcommand\AB@affilnote[1]{\textsuperscript{#1}}
```

between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`. This last change must be done *before* you actually use `\author` and `\affil`.

[image: output of the following code]

```
\documentclass[25pt, portrait, margin=0in, innermargin=0.5in, blockverticalspace=0.5in, colspace=0.5in, ]{tikzposter} %17, 20, 25pt  
\geometry{paperwidth=45in, paperheight=44in}  
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  


\makeatletter  
\setlength{\TP@visibletextwidth}{43.5in} %paperwidth - margin  
\setlength{ \TP@visibletextheight}{42.5in} %paperheight - margin  
\makeatother  
\usetheme{Default} %Default, Rays, Basic, Simple, Envelope, Wave, Board, Autumn, Desert  

\usepackage{authblk} % for author affiliation in title section  
%% To avoid extra vspace between title and body % START % https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/225542/how-to-add-multiple-affiliations-in-the-tikzposter-class  
\makeatletter  
\def\maketitle{\AB@maketitle}  
\renewcommand\AB@authnote[1]{\textsuperscript{#1}}
\renewcommand\AB@affilnote[1]{\textsuperscript{#1}}
\makeatother  
% To avoid extra vspace between title and body % END  


\title{\parbox{\linewidth}{\centering This is a really long and smart title for all the work I have done on this}}

\author[1]{Smart C.}
\author[2]{J. Brainy}
\author[2]{M. Scientist}
\author[1]{S. Proffessor}

\affil[1]{University of Somewhere}
\affil[2]{Commission of Something}


\settitle{ \centering \vbox{
\@titlegraphic \\[\TP@titlegraphictotitledistance] \centering
\color{titlefgcolor} {\bfseries \Huge  \@title \par}
\vspace*{2em}
{\huge \@author \par} \vspace*{1em} {\LARGE\@institute}
}}

\renewcommand\Authfont{\bfseries}
\renewcommand\Affilfont{\bfseries}

\begin{document}  

    \maketitle  

\end{document}
```

Alternatively you could ditch all the `authblk` stuff, and do things a bit more manually, using only `\settitle` from `tikzposter`.

[image: output of the code below]

```
\documentclass[25pt, portrait, margin=0in, innermargin=0.5in, blockverticalspace=0.5in, colspace=0.5in, ]{tikzposter} %17, 20, 25pt  
\geometry{paperwidth=45in, paperheight=44in}  
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  

\makeatletter  
\setlength{\TP@visibletextwidth}{43.5in} %paperwidth - margin  
\setlength{\TP@visibletextheight}{42.5in} %paperheight - margin  
\makeatother  


\usetheme{Default} %Default, Rays, Basic, Simple, Envelope, Wave, Board, Autumn, Desert  

\title{\parbox{\linewidth}{\centering This is a really long and smart title for all the work I have done on this}}
\author{Smart C.\textsuperscript{1}, J. Brainy\textsuperscript{2}, M. Scientist\textsuperscript{2}, S. Proffessor\textsuperscript{1}}
\institute{\textsuperscript{1}University of somewhere\\\textsuperscript{2}Commission of Something}  

\settitle{ \centering \vbox{
\@titlegraphic \\[\TP@titlegraphictotitledistance] \centering
\color{titlefgcolor} {\bfseries \Huge  \@title \par}
\vspace*{2em}
{\huge\bfseries \@author \par} \vspace*{1em} {\LARGE\bfseries \@institute}
}}


\begin{document}  

    \maketitle  

\end{document}
```